# Convert this easy code from javascript to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, sorting

I need to convert this code from java to c#..

```
points = points.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.angle - b.angle;
});
```

I tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i < points.Count-1; i++)
{
    for (var j = i + 1; j < points.Count; j++)
    {
        if (points[i].angle > points[j].angle)
        {
            punct aux = points[i];
            points[i] = points[j];
            points[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't worked..
Any help?

Comment: But why can't you simply use some sorting functions available in C#?

Comment: That doesn't look like Java to start with - did you mean Javascript? (That's an entirely different language.)

Comment: Did you mean Javascript? Because that doesn't look like Java (that's not even valid).

Comment: What does `didn't work` mean? Was there an error? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Ok, ok, i edited my title . Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ, assuming `Angle` is a sortable property like a `decimal`, `integer`, etc:

```
var result = points.OrderBy(p => p.Angle);
```

Should your `Angle` be a non trivial object, or require custom sorting, you could make it implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write your own comparisson.